# NVIDIA 970 gpu load at 100% - will an NVIDIA 1050 work for this load?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

I am developing a visualization using shaders and it is currently pushing the GPU Load on my NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970 to 100% (See GPU-Z screenshot below). I'm considering buying a laptop (for portability - as my current machine is a desktop) with an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 - will it hold up under this load? Thank you!

[image]

**UPDATE:** For anyone doing a similar comparison, I am working in the currently limited space of finding a laptop with a touchscreen and a suitably powerful graphics card for my specs (above). Of those laptops available that use NVIDIA cards at the time I am asking this question (late April, 2019), all include the 1050 card except for the Microsoft Surface 2, 15" which uses a 1060. As it turns out, the 1060 performs slightly better than the 970 card I am currently using in my desktop, so has turned out to be the machine for my requirements.

Comment: You do understand that the GTX 1050, is worse in nearly imagable every way except for the clock, which isn't likely the source of your performance issues?

Comment: @Ramhound - I didn't, that's why I asked. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will it hold up under this load?

**A GTX 1050 will perform worse than the GTX 970.**

The GTX 1050 has a boost clock of 1518 MHz while the GTX 970 has a boost clock of 1178 MHz. The difference between these two frequencies is not enough to bring a huge performance boost due to a GPU clock being faster.

The GTX 970 has a Pixel 54.6 GP/sec and Texture 109.2 GT/sec vs the GTX 1050 which has Pixel 33.4 GP/sec and Texture 66.8 GT/sec.  **Additionally, the 970 GTX, has 1 GB more GDDR5 than the GTX 1050.**

**Since your workload already requires more than 3 GB VRAM, the GTX 1050 with less memory, would perform worse by this metric alone.**

The GTX 970 has 3494 GFLOPS SP and 109 GFLOPS DP.  The GTX 1050 has 2138 GFLOPS SP and 66 GFLOPS DP.  **So depending on your workload, which you don't provide an adequate description of, the GTX 1050 would perform worse by this metric alone.**

The 2240 GB/sec memory bandwidth of the GTX 970 compared to the GTX 84 GB/sec memory bandwidth of the GTX 1050 will make a huge difference.

Conclusion: **The `GM204` brings better performance in nearly every way compared to the `GP107-300-A1`**

Source:

- [GTX 970](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-970/specifications)
- [GTX 1050](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/products/10series/geforce-gtx-1050/)
- [GeForce 10 series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_10_series)
- [GeForce 900 series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_900_series)

Comment: The `GTX 1050` is an overpriced bargin bin GPU in my opionion that would only be a good replacement for an old bargin bin GPU.

Comment: Is the GTX 1060 much better? I'm in the bind of looking for a portable touchscreen (likely a laptop) with a powerful enough graphics card to run my visualization. Thanks for your help and perspective!

Comment: @gromiczek - Nvidia provides the specifications for all their GPUs.  All the analysis I performed was based on a wikipedia table and the specifications of the cards.  You made no mention of these devices being in a laptop.  The performance delta will be even greater.  1060 is also a bargain bin GPU compared to your medium high-end 970.

Answer (score 0):

I seriously doubt that you can achieve a dramatic increase in performance by
buying another laptop, not the least because of the power requirements
involved in running a high-end video card.
For your needs a desktop is probably better suited.

I understand that you need much better performance and more video RAM.
The good news is that these two parameters are usually interdependent.

A very good resource for comparative speed of GPUs is the
[PassMark High End Video Card Chart](https://www.videocardbenchmark.net/high_end_gpus.html).

You will see there that the GeForce GTX 980 is evaluated at 11,387 operations.
I note that the GeForce GTX 1050 is rated as 4,689, which is *much worse* than
your current GPU.

To get 50% more performance, you will need to go to around 17,000 operations,
which will place you above the level of an GeForce RTX 2080,
priced at $680.

To get 25% more performance, you will need to go to above 14,000 operations,
which will place you above the level of an GeForce GTX 1080 Ti,
priced at $800. Since the Ti models have a large amount of memory,
you might get an even better improvement.

I reproduce the relevant part of the chart below:

[image]